# P is undecidable and not semidecidable, Q is undecidable and semidecidable and P ⊂ Q

Tags: undecidability, semi-decidability

My problem: Define two sets P and Q of words (that is, two problems) such that: P is undecidable and not semidecidable, Q is undecidable and semidecidable and P ⊂ Q

Comment: I need to find an example of P and Q that satisfy those conditions, but I can't find it

Comment: Keep trying, then. The only way to understand these concepts is to solve questions. You get better with time.

Comment: I tried with Q as the set of turing machines which halt on empty input and P as the set of turing machines which halt on every input.

P is undecidable and not semidecidable,Q is undecidable and semidecidable but I don't think that P ⊂ Q

Comment: Hint: If a machine halts on every input, then in particular it halts on the empty input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Following the OP's suggestion, let $P$ be the set of all TMs halting on every input, and let $Q$ be the set of all TMs halting on the empty input. It is known that $Q$ is undecidable and semidecidable (indeed, $\Sigma_1^P$-complete) and that $P$ is undecidable and not semidecidable (indeed, $\Pi_2^P$-complete). Moreover, $P \subseteq Q$ since if $T \in P$ then $T$ halts on every input, and in particular $T$ halts on the empty input, so that $T \in Q$.

Comment: thanks but why Q is undecidable and semidecidable ?

Comment: That was your suggestion. You'll have to come up with the explanation yourself. You got enough help.